# Can my copper bottom pot be fixed?

Tags: equipment, pot, copper-cookware

My favorite copper bottom pot is finally losing it's bottom. In fact, everyone uses this pot. However, I've hidden it so no one can use it until I find a solution. I hate the thought of tossing it and hope someone can help.
Kinda desperate, Angela

Comment: it would help if we had pictures of what exactly is going wrong with the pot.

Comment: if you mean the copper is wearing off, I have never seen a service that will re-plate the copper on the bottom. I have some Revereware pans that my parents bought in the late 50s and the copper on them is showing no signs of wearing off. Newer pots may have thinner copper coating that is more prone to wearing off.

Comment: The name for people who repair pots is ‘tinker’ but the term has come to mean people who make things, so I have no idea how to figure out if people still do it professionally.  You might see if there are any metal smiths (tin smith, blacksmith, etc) who also work in copper.  Jewelers work in metal, so might be able to do it, too.

Comment: I'm not sure how copper wears off, unless you are rubbing it.

Comment: I'm new, therefore not sure how to add a picture.. yet. The copper bottom is not wearing off, it's separating. Like it's been soldered to the stainless steel pot and now it's becoming unsoldered (is that even a term?)

Comment: Angela: is the copper in the form of a round, flat plate, on the bottom of the pot?

Comment: Yes it is round and flat. I would add a picture but apparently I'm not doing it right

Comment: Is there another community where my question would be better received and possibly resolved?